# Base case of recursion function for Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to write the function `void fib(int arr[], int n)`, which would fill the array with Fibonacci numbers until index n.

I've tried to find base cases, and chose these:

```
void fib(int arr[], int num){

    int arrLength = num + 1;

    if(num<0){
        return;
    }else if(num == 0){
        arr[num] = 1;
    }else if(num == 1){
        arr[num-1] = 1;
        arr[num] = 1;
    }    
}
```

But, as you can see, I did not find recursive method itself.

Here's sample output, for example, for call **fib(arr, 5)**:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 2 3 5 8
```

My `main` function for testing case:

```
int main(){ 

    int n = 10, i;
    int arr[n+1];

    fib(arr, n);

    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        printf("%i ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any other way to make base cases more "elegant"? Also, I would truly appreciate hints using which I could fill the array with numbers starting from 2 with recursive option.

Comment: You don't need to recurse, you just need to loop.

Comment: @tadman I'd love to, but I was asked to recurse

Comment: Then better get to recursing! Hint: `fib(&a[1], num - 1)`.

Comment: @tadman Sorry but what why would it store in the address? Still cannot proceed the recursive option of it

Comment: That's just a pointer to the first element, which can also be interpreted as an array, since in C they're often interchangeable.

Comment: Is `num` the number of elements in the array, or the iteration point? If it's the iteration point you have no way of knowing when to stop, since the size of the array has been lost.

Comment: It appears you are just using function not recursion. why?

Comment: @tadman size would be num+1 I guess

Comment: @Azhar I just don't have a recursive case yet

Comment: Where's the test harness where this is called? That'd help explain how this is running.

Comment: @honeysoybeefwithrice forget my comment.

Comment: @honeysoybeefwithrice Okay will try in answer to implement this using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You question is asking for recursion but the program you write is just using function, because of this reason I am writing very basic code for your better understanding, you can improve this after understanding the flow and functionality or ask new question with some work.
Below one is a working code tested on TurboC, I am sharing complete test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX 100

void fib(int *arr, int num, int a, int b, int term){

    if(term == 0 && term <= num){
        arr[term] = 1;
        term++;
        fib(arr,num,a,b,term);
    }else if(term ==1 && term <= num){
        arr[term] = 1;
        term++;
        fib(arr,num,a,b,term);
    }else if(term <= num){
        arr[term] = a+b;
        term++;
        fib(arr,num,b,a+b,term);
    }
}

void main()
{
   int firstTerm = 1;//First term of fibbo series
   int secondTerm = 1;//Second term of fibbo series
   int tracker = 0; // Tracker to track how much term we printed
   int i;//To run loop here to check array after recursive function
   int ar[MAX],n=5;// n is number of term we want to print
   clrscr();
   fib(ar,n,firstTerm,secondTerm,tracker);//recursive function call

   // below is printing array to check 
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
    printf("%d\t",ar[i]);
   }
   getch();
}
```

One thing I have to suggest is, if n is 5 then you just get 1 1 2 3 5, In code I did according to your requirement, so here it will print 1 1 2 3 5 8

Comment: @honeysoybeefwithrice , if this answer works for you please mark as confirm. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I'd state that the "elegant" solution should be a simple loop, without any recursion, but let's see how it could be done in the less efficient and more error prone way.

```
// I'll assume that the function signature can't be changed
void fib(int arr[], int num)
{
    // In the general case, use the well known recurrence relation.
    if ( num > 1 )
    {
        // Use recursion here to calculate the previous elements of the array.
        fib(arr, /* ... */);
        //       ^^^^^^^^^  Can you figure out what index should be passed here?

        // Then, calculate the element at index num using the recurrence relation.
        arr[num] = arr[num - 1] + arr[num - 2];
        //             ^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^ Note the indices.
        //                                    Are those values alredy known?
    }
    // When num is 0 or 1, we can't use the general formula. Can you tell why?
    else if ( num >= 0 )
    {
        fib(arr, /* ... */);
        //       ^^^^^^^^^   Same as before.
        arr[num] = 1;
    }
    // If num is less than 0, it just do nothing.
}
```